# BitmapFactory.decodeFile Question in Android

Tags: android

I used the BitmapFactory.decodeFile method to decode an image file in Android.

About the output bitmap, what is the property of the Bitmap.Config ?

(ALPHA_8 , ARGB_4444, ARGB_8888 or RGB_565 ?)

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking what the default is, or what those values mean ?

Comment: I want to ask what the config will be of the output bitmap after calling BitmapFactory.decodeFile method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for more information on these values you must read this blog entry: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/

edit: You're asking what the value of Bitmap.Config will be after using the Bitmap.decodeFile():Bitmap method.

According to API you can use either decodeFile with param pathName:String or with params pathName:String and opts:Bitmap.Options. That second method accepts options for decoding. One of these is a Bitmap.Config param with this information (again from API):

public Bitmap.Config    inPreferredConfig   If this is non-null, the decoder will try to decode into this internal configuration.

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to ask what the config will be of the output bitmap after calling BitmapFactory.decodeFile method

Comment: please update your initial question with this extra information. I'll answer in another answer.